# What's the equivalent of cache_clear_all()?

Tags: 8, caching

What's the equivalent of `cache_clear_all()` in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cache api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21CacheBackendInterface.php/function/CacheBackendInterface%3A%3AinvalidateAll/8.2.x). It would be somthing like

```
\Drupal::cache('bin')->invalidateAll();
```

Or if you want to remove the entries and not just invalidate them:

```
\Drupal::cache('bin')->delete('variables')
```

where bin is a valid cache bin such as menu, render, page ...etc.

Comment: invalidateAll() invalidates all, not just a specific key, that would be delete() or deleteMultiple(). You most likely don't want to use invalidate* but delete* because the invalidate methods just mark it as invalida but don't actually delete it. That only makes sense if you have a use case whre you might want to load that with $allow_invalid = TRUE

Comment: But it's limited to the bin passed to invalidate?

Comment: limited to the bin, but everything in that, yes. cache_clear_all() had a about 7 different functions depending on what you passed in and that example above cleared a specific entry, so the equivalent would be  \Drupal::cache('bin')->delete('variables')